# Cannot find kotlin-reflection.jar when calling Kotlin from a Java program

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to use a Typescript generation library called ts-generator. It lives at https://github.com/ntrrgc/ts-generator. It looks pretty cool.

My problem is that when try to use the library, I get a

```
kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError
```

The error message also says that I'm likely missing kotlin-reflect.jar

The jar, however, does appear to be on my classpath. I've made a SSCE that I think demonstrates my problem, as follows.

My gradle file is

```
jar {
    baseName = 'eiep_codegen'
    version = '1' 
}
repositories {
     maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ntrrgc:ts-generator:1.1.0' 
}
task execute(type:JavaExec) {
   main = mainClass
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

and my code I want to run is

```
package testing;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference;
import kotlin.reflect.KClass;
import me.ntrrgc.tsGenerator.TypeScriptGenerator;
import me.ntrrgc.tsGenerator.VoidType;

public class GenerateTSClasses 
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }

        List<KClass<?>> roots = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<KClass<?>, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();

        roots.add(new ClassReference(GenerateMe.class));

        System.out.println
        (
            new TypeScriptGenerator
            (
                    roots,
                    mappings,
                    new ArrayList<>(),
                    new HashSet<>(),
                    "Hey There", 
                    VoidType.NULL
            ).getDefinitionsText()
        );
    }
}
```

The output when I run the task is as follows. The first bit is a dump of the classpath, which has kotlin-reflect-1.2.10.jar in the list. The second part is the exception.

```
/Users/joe/git/4.x/ei-sources/eiep_codegen/build/classes/java/main/
/Users/joe/git/4.x/ei-sources/eiep_codegen/build/resources/main
/Users/joe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.ntrrgc/ts-generator/1.1.0/3c9db2d2350dae022e3d4c8e77589a3e7f50db2b/ts-generator-1.1.0.jar
/Users/joe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.10/19bc012f8c4cd6b705bd6512263777cc19bcf259/kotlin-reflect-1.2.10.jar
/Users/joe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.10/b9bf650516989595a5390e5a54181e16347208ac/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.10.jar
/Users/joe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
        at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:86)
...
```

My question is - does anyone know what could be causing this problem? (I'm assuming that it can't be the version number after the jar file, but I'll verify that, too).

EDIT - I also coped the jar files across manually and ran the program from the command line using java --classpath. The names of the jar files (as you'd imagine) make no difference to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

See [Kotlin docuementation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html).

> On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file (kotlin-reflect.jar). This is done to reduce the required size of the runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features. **If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added to the classpath of your project.**

Or you can choose to add it to your dependencies. Read more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies).

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
```

Comment: Is that one different to /Users/joe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.10/19bc012f8c4cd6b705bd6512263777cc19bcf259/kotlin-reflect-1.2.10.jar?